# How to configure first TPDO in DS402

Tags: canopen

I want to configure a TPDO to get the statusword. Does anybody know how to do this? If i want to configure TPDO 1 the COBID has to be 1800h right? What else must be specified?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually configure the TPDOs with the manufacturer configuration tool. TPDO 1 has usually 0x180 + Node ID, so if your CAN peripheral has the ID 12 the TPDO1 is 0x192.

Comment: I've read some pdf but i still don't understand what data will be sent. Could you please post an example how to configure  TPDO1 to get the statusword after homing operation?

Comment: I can't undestand what you mean with "afeter homing operation". When I Configure the TPDO, it's send every Xms or every change (I can configure it). To configure it I use the manufacturer application, which is a drag & drop application, there is a screen capture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QiS9x.png
I don't have a driver here to test it, but when I enable the driver using the Control Word the Status word changes to singal it's ready or if there is an error.

Comment: Sorry may be i should provide more context. We wrote a C# application to communicate over CANopen and DS402. We configure TPDO be sending the following data (example): 0x640 0x23 0x00 0x1A 0x01 0x10 0x00 0x41 0x60. 0x640 is the cobid (node id is 40h). I know that 0x23 means that exactly 4 bytes are send. And 0x41 0x60 specify the statusword. I'm very new to these things. My colleague has left the company and know it's up to me to finish the project. I need to get the statusword containing the information about succeeded homing. This is if bit 13 is set to 1. But i don't get the statusword.

Comment: Ok, you want to configure the TPDO writing the object dictionary using SDO's. There is a picture of the object dictionary with the status word configured on the TPDO1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZogqM.jpg. May be you have to write a value 1 on the address 0x1A00, subindex 0.